# WHERE __ IN ('1', '2', . . .) only returns matches matching last twelve conditions

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have observed strange behavior using IN in the WHERE clause of a HiveQL query.
I am running `Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37`. The following query successfully outputs a `.csv` called `test36b.csv` for all records with an `enl_id` equal to `'177110382'`.

```
hive -e  " SELECT
first_name,
enl_id
FROM enl_dev2.fuller27tethered2to2_compress WHERE enl_id IN ('177110382') "  | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  >  test36b.csv;
```

The same, albeit longer query, successfully outputs a `.csv` called `test36b.csv`, but no records with an `enl_id` equal to `'177110382'` are returned. In fact, the `.csv` only contains records where the `enl_id` is one of the last twelve `enl_ids` included in the `IN` clause above. The only difference in my code is that more `enl_ids` are included in the `IN` clause. Is there any reason why I might be observing such behavior?

```
hive -e  " SELECT
first_name,
enl_id
FROM enl_dev2.fuller27tethered2to2_compress WHERE enl_id IN ('168499285','177110382','252987616','252987616','550701456','550701456','4420299521','4420299521','4543445723','4543445723','4656557207','4656557207','4814906984','4814906984','4846736314','4846736314','5037514651','5037514651','5208451646', '5230790146', '5359847644', '5359847644', '5474957334', '5474957334', '5675919751', '5675919751', '5912174384', '5912174384', '6323575713', '6323575713', '6458995919', '6459273819', '6467436756', '6532560778', '6532560778') "  | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  >  test36d.csv;
```